# Computed Field in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains a date column. Whenever the client enters a form, the date column for the specific form record is filled with the current date. What I'm trying to do is from another table have a computed column go over all of the records from the original table, and if one of the rows under the date column is empty (meaning the specific form wasn't opened), I want a record that indicates whether ALL of the forms were opened to be 1, otherwise 0 (if one of the forms wasn't yet opened).

I have a table called tblFormAlerts which has 'formName', 'dateViewed' columns. Whenever the client enters the form, the dateViewed column is filled with the current date. I want to create another table called 'tblGeneralAlerts, that has a 'type' column, and 'status' column. The type is for example "formAlerts" and the 'status' indicates whether all of the forms were viewed or not.

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not _fields_.

Comment: I'll repeat it `Tables have columns, not fields.`. Tables aren't spreadsheets. You can't create a calculated column that refers to other *rows* in the same table, much less other tables. That's what queries and views are for. Join the tables together and calculate what you want

Comment: I'm struggling to follow your narrative - you start describing some things but never seem to finish them. For the tables, at least, could we have some actual names for them and for the column(s) which are relevant here? (Preferably in the form of cut-down `CREATE TABLE` statements for us to be able to copy & paste) And then try to describe *separately* what the relevance of the "form" is?

Comment: `I'm here to clarify`. Explain the *actual* problem, not how you think the solution should look like. You have people filling forms every day. By the wording it looks like there's a *standard* set of forms that need to be filled every day, and you want to find who missed which forms? Or simply find dates on which even 1 form went missing?

Comment: No problem:
I have a table called tblFormAlerts which has 'formName', 'dateViewed' columns. Whenever the client enters the form, the dateViewed column is filled with the current date. I want to create another table called 'tblGeneralAlerts, that has a 'type' column, and 'status' column. The type is for example "formAlerts" and the 'status' indicates whether all of the forms were viewed or not.

Comment: Please edit your question and add any clarifications that way as opposed to putting them in hard to read comments :)

Comment: If you have say 10 forms then does the `tblFormAlerts` contain 10 rows, or is it 10 rows per day or is there perhaps other columns involved like one for the user? Anyway I doubt you need a new column, sounds like this can be solved with a simple query.

Comment: The table tblFormAlerts contains 10 rows, pretty straightforward.

Comment: So what happens if two clients open ten forms? Do you still have ten rows? How do you capture this for two different clients?

Comment: The server is built of one database per client, and there is a tblFormAlerts table in each of them.

Comment: So basically what you need is something like `SELECT COUNT(*) = 0 FROM tblFormAlerts WHERE dateViewed IS NULL`?